# USB audio not working when plugged in during boot

Tags: linux, usb, audio, usb-audio, dock

I have a problem with the audio in my ThinkPad OneLink Pro Dock not working with Linux. I have had this problem with OpenSUSE 42.1, Tumbleweed and Fedora 23. I think I will have it with any other distro two because this looks like more of a kernel issue.

The dock comes with a USB audio adapter which lsusb says is "Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0d8c:0170 C-Media Electronics, Inc.". My problem is that I cannot get any audio from this device if my laptop is booted with it plugged in. The best that I can do is to get a bit of a crackling sound. If I were to plug it in after booting then I can get the audio working. Getting the audio or the crack does require a lot of messing around with PulseAudio but I guess I could automate that.

My main problem is that I need it to work when I boot with it plugged in because that I what I do most and it would just be really impractical to have to plug and unplug the dock the whole time.

I have already reported this as a bug but I am wondering if there might be some workaround that I can use in the mean time. I think maybe I could delay the loading of some modules?

Comment: @Sukminder it's not allowing to unload it, but I don't see how the HDA can be involved with a USB adapter?